# Turning flat file into matrix: based on specific date ranges for two unique groups

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large flat file consisting of mark-recapture data for grizzly bears.  To analyze (in program MARK) these data need to be transformed into a matrix.  The dataset is approximately 10,000 rows long

An example data set is as follows:

```
Date          TrapType    BearID   
01-01-2013    Corral       1
01-24-2013    Corral       1
02-14-2013    Tree         1
01-04-2013    Corral       2
01-08-2013    Corral       2
01-18-2013    Tree         2
03-01-2013    Tree         2
01-01-2013    Coral        3
03-03-2013    Tree         4
```

Date is the day the site was checked
Trap type is the type of trap used to collect the sample, Corrals are only deployed from Jan1- Jan 30, Trees are deployed from Jan1-March15
Bear ID is the individual identifier

I need to create a capture matrix using specific date ranges, but the tricky part is the date ranges will not be the same for the two trap types (Corral and Tree)

I would like to group captures at Corral sites every 10 days and captures at Tree sites every 30 days

So, the capture matrix for the above data, with rows being bears and columns being capture sessions, would look like:

```
(Corral Jan1-9) (Corral Jan10-19)  (Corral Jan20-30)  (Tree Jan1-30)  (Tree Feb1-30)  
(Tree Mar 1-30)
1    1   0   1   0   1   0                      
2    1   0   0   1   0   0
3    1   0   0   0   0   0
4    0   0   0   0   0   1
```

The real file wouldn't need spaces, I just added them so it was easier to view.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

I've tried to break the two trap types up and use table commands, but I'm really quite green when it comes to R and my toolkit of commands is limited.

Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method. First, here's your data

```
dd<-data.frame(
    Date = c("01-01-2013", "01-24-2013", "02-14-2013", "01-04-2013", 
        "01-08-2013", "01-18-2013", "03-01-2013", "01-01-2013", "03-03-2013"), 
    TrapType = c("Corral", "Corral", "Tree", "Corral", 
        "Corral", "Tree", "Tree", "Corral", "Tree"),
    BearID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4)
)
```

First I make sure the Date column are actually Dates and convert the BearID to a factor

```
dd$Date <- as.Date(as.character(dd$Date), format="%m-%d-%Y")
dd$BearID <-factor(dd$BearID)
```

Now i'll reshape the two trap types separately using `subset`, `table` and `cut.Date` to use different breaks for each of the trap types. Note that R may have different ideas about how long each of those ranges are. If you want to be more specific, you could pass a vector of Dates to the `breaks=` parameter of `cut()`.

```
ctable<-with(subset(dd, TrapType=="Corral"), 
    table(BearID, cut(Date, breaks="10 days")))
colnames(ctable)<-paste("Corral", colnames(ctable))
ttable<-with(subset(dd, TrapType=="Tree"), 
    table(BearID, cut(Date, breaks="30 days")))
colnames(ttable)<-paste("Tree", colnames(ttable))
```

Finally, I put these two tables together to get the final data set

```
newdata<-cbind(ttable, ctable)
```

This method should work with many more date ranges.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick.  Much appreciated.  I tried to keep my example simple and your answer brought me a long ways in my understanding.  I have since been trying to alter your code so that I can break the Tree trap types up non-equal breaks, i.e., I may want to break the trees on 2013-01-20, then 2013-02-30, and finally 2013-03-10.

Comment: @user3653140 Like I said, you can supply an explicit break vector to cut. Something like `breaks=as.Date(c("2013-01-20", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-10"))` if you don't like the ones it automatically creates.

Comment: I was missing the c after as.Date.  Rookie move.  Thanks so much for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of transformation from the long to the wide format. But here you should preprocess your data before using some specific R tools like `dcast` or `reshape`. You can do this for example:

```
## First I read your data   
xx <- read.table(text='Date          TrapType    BearID   
01-01-2013    Corral       1
01-24-2013    Corral       1
02-14-2013    Tree         1
01-04-2013    Corral       2
01-08-2013    Corral       2
01-18-2013    Tree         2
03-01-2013    Tree         2
01-01-2013    Coral        3
03-03-2013    Tree         4',header=TRUE)

## Coerce column Date to a valid date
xx$Date <- as.Date(xx$Date,format='%m-%d-%Y')
## Create a new column that aggregate corrals type and date
## this the tricky part!!
xx <- transform(xx,Type=
ifelse(TrapType=='Corral',{
  dd = as.numeric(format(xx$Date,'%d'))
  ifelse(dd<10,'Corral Jan1-9',
         ifelse(dd<20,'Corral Jan10-19','Corral Jan20-30'))
},{
  mm = as.numeric(format(xx$Date,'%m'))
  ifelse(mm<2,'Tree Jan1-31',
         ifelse(mm<3,'Tree Feb1-28','Tree Mar 1-31'))
}))

## put it in the wide format
library(reshape2)
dcast(BearID~Type,data=xx)
  BearID Corral Jan1-9 Corral Jan20-30 Tree Feb1-28 Tree Jan1-31 Tree Mar 1-31
1      1             1               1            1            0             0
2      2             2               0            0            1             1
3      3             0               0            0            1             0
4      4             0               0            0            0             1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!!  I notice that the corral Jan10-19 session is lost, because there were no captures during this time.  However, this is still information that I can use.  I wonder how to incorporate this.  Mr.Flick's answer below retains this column, but oddly enough drops a Tree column which must just be a small error somewhere.  Regardless, these solutions have been extremely helpful.  I look forward to becoming a contributing member of this community